# NLog and SQLite Error

Tags: c#, sqlite, nlog

I am trying to get `NLog` to properly log to a **SQLite** database.
I am able to interact with the SQLite database aside from `NLog`.

When I force Internal Logging of `NLog`, I see the following error:

> Error initializing target Database Target[db] System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.SQLite' from assembly 'NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c'.

My `NLog` configuration has the following parameters:

- `dbProvider="System.Data.SQLite"` `keepConnection="false"`
- `connectionString="Data Source=${basedir}\Database.s3db;"`
- `commandText="INSERT into Log(Timestamp, Loglevel, Logger, Callsite,
  Message) values(@Timestamp, @Loglevel, @Logger, @Callsite, @Message)"`

What am I missing?

Comment: If you're running this outside of VS, have you ensured the referenced dll has 'copy local' set to true?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am running from within VS.  Would this still be relevant?

Comment: IN that case, no. Sorry. You might want to check that the version of the CLR you are running is the correct version for the DLL (try changing the .NET version and profile on the build tab of the project)

Answer (score 1):

Its a very old question but my answer might help if anyone else faces the same issue:

In my case the version number in NLog.config file was the issue which was not the one what I have added System.Data.SQLite.dll. To do so:

- Right click on System.Data.SQLite.dll and then click Properties
- Click Details for actual version number
- Write correct version in NLog.config file

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the NLog configuration to point to System.Data.SQLite.EF6 as the dbProvider and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Install the following nuget package :
Install-Package System.Data.SQLite -Version 1.0.115