# NLog Configuration for SQLCipher Database

Tags: wpf, sqlite, nlog, sqlcipher

We are attempting to use **NLog** (https://github.com/NLog/NLog) to log certain things to a table named **Logs** that is contained within our **SQLCipher** (https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher) Database. We are receiving several different errors, but the one that is currently relevant is shown in the NLog internal logging file below

```
2019-08-15 11:46:15.4789 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
2019-08-15 11:46:15.5587 Info Adding target DatabaseTarget(Name=DBLog)
2019-08-15 11:46:15.6265 Info Found 38 configuration items
2019-08-15 11:46:15.7622 Info Configuration initialized.

2019-08-15 11:46:15.7751 Info NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c. File version: 4.6.6.10303. Product version: 4.6.6.

2019-08-15 11:47:04.6315 Error DatabaseTarget(Name=DBLog): Error when writing to database. Exception: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 26: '**file is not a database**'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.<PrepareAndEnumerateStatements>d__62.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.WriteEventToDatabase(LogEventInfo logEvent, String connectionString)
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
```

The **current** NLog config file is as follows (the password and connectionString are actually correct, I've just renamed them in this example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      internalLogLovel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="file.txt"
      internalLogToConsole="true"
      internalLogIncludeTimestamp="true">

  <targets>

    <!-- DATABASE LOGGER-->
    <target name="DBLog"
            xsi:type="Database"
            dbProvider="Microsoft.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, Microsoft.Data.SQLite"
            keepConnection="false"
            connectionString="Data Source=C:\Folder\DatabaseName.db"
            dbPassword="password"
            commandText="INSERT INTO Logs (Message) VALUES ('Test');">
    </target>

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="DBLog" />
  </rules>

</nlog>
```

I think the problem may lie in the dbProvider property, but I am unsure what is needed in order to get NLog to work with SQLCipher (encrypted version of SQLite3)

Thanks in advance!

**Edit** (adding for JAZ)

```
2019-08-16 08:59:51.4363 Error Database Target[DBLog]: Error initializing target Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.SQLite' from assembly 'NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c'.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.SetConnectionType()
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.InitializeTarget()
   at NLog.Targets.Target.Initialize(LoggingConfiguration configuration)
```

Comment: Try just dbProvider="System.Data.SQLite" and make sure whatever user the app is running under has write, maybe full, access to the file and location.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but when I use just System.Data.SQLite is throws an error about NLog not containing the assembly for System.Data,SQLite. I can comment more the more accurate error log information tomorrow when I get home

Comment: @JAZ I ended up building out a custom logging tool using our ORM for the time being, but would still like to be able to implement NLog to handle these kinds of tasks. Any other suggestions? I have added the exact error I get when trying your suggestion to the original question.

Comment: From the error message it leads me to believe that SQLite drivers are not found or can't be loaded. From what I remember there were separate support dll's that need to be installed for SQLite.  Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795017/nlog-and-sqlite-error or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602139/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite-on-target-machine

Comment: @JAZ Hmm, I agree with you there, but when I look back to the original error that was received -- **NLog** was able to **resolve** the SQLite drivers when I was using the **dbProvider** of **"Microsoft.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, Microsoft.Data.SQLite".** The underlying issue seems to be that my current NLog configuration is not correct when it comes to working with the **SQLCipher** version of SQLite. I've tried using several of the SQLCipher DB providers as well such as SQLPCLRaw.provider.sqlcipher with no luck. It may be that SQLCipher does not work with NLog, due to the encryption?

Comment: When using `dbProvider="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite"`, then one must also remember to install the matching nuget-package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just doing this (Injecting the PRAGMA key in the commandText):

```xml
    <!-- DATABASE LOGGER-->
    <target name="DBLog"
            xsi:type="Database"
            dbProvider="Microsoft.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, Microsoft.Data.SQLite"
            keepConnection="false"
            connectionString="Data Source=redacted\redacted.db"
            commandText="PRAGMA key = 'redacted';INSERT INTO Logs (Message) VALUES ('Test');">
    </target>
```

See also: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-dotnet/

Comment: Well congrats, you found my post on S.O.! I was in the middle of answering it myself and linking back to [our discussion](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3551) for reference if anyone else happens to run into something similar. However, I will go ahead and mark your answer here! Thanks again

- dmtomczyk